# R ggplot: Dynamic align geom_text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have made a funnel chart to show conversion through various stages **A > B > C > D**

Below is the R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
options(scipen = 999)  # turns of scientific notations like 1e+40

stage <- c("A","A", "B","B","C","C","D","D")
percent <- c(-100,100,-75,75,-50,50,-10,10)
funnel_df <- data.frame(stage, percent)

# X Axis Breaks and Labels 
brks <- seq(-100, 100, 10)
lbls = paste0(as.character(seq(0, 100, 5), "%"))

# Plot
ggplot(funnel_df, aes(x = stage, y = percent)) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6) +   # draw the bars
  geom_text(data=funnel_df, 
            aes(label= paste(round(percent), '%'), hjust = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1)),
            color='white') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks,   # Breaks
                     labels = lbls) + # Labels
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="Email Campaign Funnel") +
  theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette
```

Below is the output that I get:
[image]

The plot is appearing correctly. However, I want the text labels on the bars to always be in the center of the bar. I know that I can shift the labels using **hjust** argument. However, in my case, Stage A will always be 100% but Stages B, C, and D will change dynamically. So I cannot hardcode the values inside **hjust** argument. Is there a way I can dynamically center align the text labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center of the plot is always at y = 0 (y, because you've flipped the coordinates). So you can center the text by setting its y-value to 0, as in

```
ggplot(funnel_df, aes(x = stage, y = percent)) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6) +   # draw the bars
  geom_text(data=funnel_df[1:nrow(funnel_df) %% 2 == 0, ], # only want to positive percents
            aes(y = 0, label= paste(round(percent), '%')), # y = 0 is centered
            color='white') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks,   # Breaks
                     labels = lbls) + # Labels
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="Email Campaign Funnel") +
  theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette
```

Produces:

[image: Percents are centered automatically, regardless of bar width (as long as bars are centered on 0)]